# OpenGL (ES 2.0 but not specific to ES): is GL_STATIC_DRAW meant for use with glBufferData?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

The application I am concerned with right now is a 3d model viewer. The user will very occasionally load in a large new mesh to render, and the old mesh can, should (must) be thrown away.

Because of this, `GL_STATIC_DRAW` is clearly the right hint for the VBO.

What I'm a little unsure of at this point is whether to `glDeleteBuffers()` my VBO and IBO, also `glDeleteVertexArrays[OES]()` my VAO, or do none of those and just `glBufferData()` the VBO and IBO with my newly loaded mesh without having to delete and re-gen anything *or* re-define `glVertexAttribPointer` VAO state. (Sub-question: If I only delete my VBO and then re-gen it, but I leave my VAO intact, can I still skip `glVertexAttribPointer()`?)

If indeed OpenGL will discard the previous data in the VBO if I call `glBufferData()`, then this is perfect. As far as I've read `glBufferData()` is supposed to reallocate the VBO.

But really, what I'm looking for is a concrete explanation of what would be different between me re-loading up to the different layers of this onion, and how far up I need to go if all I want is to change my vertex and index buffer content (the raw geometry) in the application, or if there even exists a conceivable situation where one might need to regenerate or delete VBOs at all. I do see that the same VBO might be usefully shared between different sets of VAOs, and I can imagine a situation where you've got some VAO's that you'll never use again so you'd deallocate them, but it seems like the VBOs can just continue to get recycled if there exists the API for you to reallocate the data contained within.

I find all of the tutorials and explanations out there only deal with helping you to set stuff up, but now that I've got that stage figured out it's not too clear how to get the rest of these details right.

Comment: VAOs do not have significant overhead, think of them as lightweight state blocks. They are not responsible for actual data store (VBOs do this), they persistently save states needed to draw one or more VBOs. Now, they can become an issue if you keep VAOs around that reference VBOs that no longer exist, but the burden of preventing this from happening is really on your shoulders and not OpenGL's. I rarely delete VAOs, if one's not needed anymore it goes into a pool of unused VAOs for re-use, this keeps dynamic allocation of OpenGL names to a minimum; works well for other types of objects too.

Comment: Aha. so you are treating VAOs the same as I intend to treat my VBOs. As handles in a resource pool that will continually get reused.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think deleting your vertex *array* object will have any effect on the contents of the *buffer* object. Deleting an FBO will not affect the storage of the textures or renderbuffers attached to it, and neither will deleting a VAO affect the storage of any buffer objects attached to it.

As far as the standard is concerned, you can do what you like. Hints are *hints*; you aren't required to follow them.

And as far as AMD is concerned, you can still do whatever you like. The reason there is because, thanks to people not understanding how the hints work, people *have done* whatever they like to the point where AMD pretty much *ignores* the hint entirely. It'll watch your usage pattern for the buffer object and move it around until you figure out how you intend to actually use it.

NVIDIA actually cares about the hints and holds you to them. To the extent that the hints are well-defined enough to hold you to them. If you use the wrong hint, you get degraded performance forever. Whereas AMD will eventually figure out what you *really* meant.

In any case, if you want to actually be true to the hint, `GL_STATIC_DRAW` is intended to mean, "you will upload to this buffer object exactly once". Now how that's supposed to reconcile with reallocation of a buffer object is up to you.

However, if you would like to guess at the ARB's opinion is, consider [the recent ARB_buffer_storage 4.4 feature](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage). There, they explicitly *disallow* reallocation of a buffer object's storage entirely (regardless of hinting). You could take that as a "hint" that reallocating storage (outside of [using `glBufferData` to invalidate an existing buffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Buffer_re-specification)) is a bad idea, regardless of the usage hint you use.

Also, from buffer_storage, the "equivalent" of `GL_STATIC_DRAW` *forbids* you from doing anything to upload to it from client storage. Once it's there, you could copy to it from some other buffer, or use it as some other destination for in-GL processes. But you can't mutate it's contents. You can only delete it.

I would take that as a hint that `GL_STATIC_DRAW` was intended to mean "delete, don't reallocate or re-upload to."

Now what that means for OpenGL ES is beyond me. It depends on how different implementations implement their buffer's storage (which is why asking about the behavior of both desktop GL and GL ES implementations is wrong). However, considering that mobile GPUs generally don't have two separate pools of memory, I imagine that they really don't care. Sure, an implementation could allocate the memory as uncached or something to make access to it faster or whatever. But beyond that, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Great, thanks for bringing in references to things that only someone of your caliber would know. ;)  I think I'll probably be fine if I just use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW then, and see if I can't make `glBufferData` work.

Comment: I'd like to throw in, that if the contents of "the" buffer change seldom, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW may be not what you actually want (it means that you'll make changes to the contents eventually). Deleting the buffer and allocating a new one and loading up the data in a GL_STATIC_DRAW fashion sounds far more reasonable for a model viewer, where the data contained in the buffer will change only when a new model is loaded.

Comment: @StevenLu: I agree with Datenwolf. Deleting the buffer is more in tune with what appears to be the scenario of usage here. Especially since you would be allocating a new buffer of an arbitrary size.